# Extracting a part of a massive csv file from command line

Tags: command-line, scripts, csv

I want to read parts of a big csv file between rows n and m and between columns p and q.
Is there an easy way to do this easily with the shell? (Are there commands I should read the doc's? otherwise, I'll write a python script)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821360/bash-pull-certain-lines-from-a-file appears to cover this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a script that I adjusted (good idea the (N+1)q part!) thanks to @chronitis comment and the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821360/bash-pull-certain-lines-from-a-file):

```
#! /bin/bash 
#
N=10
M=20
P=2
Q=3
sed -n "$N,${M}p; $((M+1))q" $1 | cut -d, -f$P-$Q
```

Save the file as for example `cut_csv`, make it executable and use as

```
cut_csv file
```

It can be made fancier by accepting the N,M,P,Q parameters as input etc, but I use it seldomly so I normally simply edit the file.

**How it works**:

The main command is the following (let's suppose N=10, M=20, P=2, Q=3); the shell substitutes the variables and the last line will become: (1)

```
sed -n "10,20p ; 21q" file | cut -d, -f2-3
```

Let's start with the first command:

```
sed -n "10,20p ; 21q" file
```

This call sed (stream editor, `man sed`) in no-print mode (`-n`) and execute the following commands on the file:

1. print (`p`) the lines between 10 and 20 (this is the `10,20p` part)
2. quit (`q`) when reading line 21 (`21q`) so that discard the rest of the file

The output of sed is piped (`|`) to `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f2-3
```

This command (`man cut`) selects fields of a line (and repeat for each line). In this case, I am telling it that the separator between fields (columns) is a commad (`-d,`), and to print out the columns between 2 and 3.

As another more complex example I often use this one:

```
sed -n "1p; 10,14p; 21q" data.csv | cut -d, -f1,4-8
```

This will select row 1 (where I have titles :-)) and rows from 10 to 14 (5 lines); then select columns 1 (time in my data...) and column from 4 to 8. It is really powerful once you get grips with it.

(1) one great way to see what the shell is doing is change the first line (which is called a *shebang*) like that:

```
#! /bin/bash -xv
```

The shell will now print every command it reads and the result of the substitutions:

```
(0)asus-rmano: part_of_csv.sh p20dedo.csv
#! /bin/bash -xv
#
N=10
+ N=10
M=20
+ M=20
P=2
+ P=2
Q=3
+ Q=3
sed -n "$N,${M}p; $((M+1))q" $1 | cut -d, -f$P-$Q
+ cut -d, -f2-3
+ sed -n '10,20p; 21q' p20dedo.csv
16:05:49,000
16:05:51,000
[...]
```

Comment: could you explain me what the line does please? (I'd like to learn writing shell scripts :) )

Comment: @bigTree,  I added the explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine awk and sed with a pipe

```
sed -n '10,50p' file.csv | awk -F ';' '{print $3 $4}'
```

10 and 50 are rows.

-F ';' is the field separator.(Semicolon in my example)

$3 and $4 are the fields to show.

Answer (score 1):

The following script using `head` and `tail` is able to print a part of a `.csv` file filtered through row and column's number.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
m="$2"
n="$3"
s="$4"
t="$5"
head -n "$n" "$1" | tail -n +"$m" | cut -d, -f "$s"-"$t"
```

Save the above script as `csv_view.sh` and make it executable.

```
chmod +x csv_view.sh
```

where,

```
m=row number where to begin
n=row number where to end
n=column number where to begin
n=column number where to end
```

**How to use**

```
./csv_view.sh mycsvfile.csv 11 32 4 7
```

It will give print row 11 to 32 and column 4 to 7 of `mycsvfile.csv`